# Subset of the Set of Prime Gaps whose elements are always even

Tags: prime-numbers

It is straight forward to see that:

$$\tag0p_{\pi(n)+1}-p_{\pi(n+1)}=0 \operatorname{iff} \quad n \in {\{p_k-1:k \in \mathbb N}\}$$

however what is not as straightforward firstly, is to show that $n$ must be the *lesser* of a pair of twin primes if the same expression is equal to $2$:

$$\tag1p_{\pi(n)+1}-p_{\pi(n+1)}=2 \quad\operatorname{iff} \quad \exists k,j \in \mathbb N \quad\operatorname{s.t}\quad n=p_k=p_j-2$$

And furthermore, establish a proof for:

$$\tag2p_{\pi(n)+1}\equiv p_{\pi(n+1)}(\operatorname{mod}2)$$

Also an equality that I have been unable to determine the truth value of:

$$\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\ln(p_n)}{\ln(p_{\pi(n)})} \Bigr\rfloor=\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\lfloor\ln(p_n)\rfloor}{\ln(p_{\pi(n)})} \Bigr\rfloor$$

To simplify $(3)$ I defined  a function $f$:
$$f(n,k)=\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\ln(n+k)}{\ln(n)} \Bigr\rfloor-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\lfloor\ln(n+k)\rfloor}{\ln(n)} \Bigr\rfloor$$

$$f(n_0,k-1)-f(n_0,k)=1$$
$$f(n_1,k-1)-f(n_1,k)=1$$
$$f(n_2,k-1)-f(n_2,k)=1$$
$$f(n,k-1)-f(n,k)=0 \quad\quad n_0 \lt n \lt n_1\land \quad\quad n_1 \lt n \lt n_2$$
Because
$$n_2-n_1 \gt n_1-n_0$$
Are we able to assert that:
$$n_2-n_1 \rightarrow \infty$$

and

$g(n,k)=\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\lfloor\ln(n+k)\rfloor}{\lfloor\ln(n)\rfloor} \Bigr\rfloor-\Bigl\lfloor \frac{\ln(n+k)}{\ln(n)} \Bigr\rfloor$

$g(n,k)=0 \operatorname{for} n \gt 7, k \gt 0$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Aside from $p=2$, all primes are odd.

Comment: Correct yes I meant to express $\tag1p_{\pi(n)+1}-p_{\pi(n+1)}$  appears to be always even

Comment: I'm sorry I go very crazy when ever I think of Goldbach's so yes $(2)$ is very obvious  I've just drunk too much tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2)$ can only fail if one of the primes $p_{\pi(n)+1}$, $p_{\pi(n+1)}$ is even and the other is odd. As $\pi(n)\le \pi(n+1)\le \pi(n)+1$, this requires $\pi(n)=\pi(n+1)=1$. So both $n$ and $n+1$ must be $\ge 2$ and at the same time $\le 3$.

Comment: So it is as easy as simply stating the difference of two odd numbers is always even?

Comment: I just don't understand if there exists a prime gap equal to any even number, and all sums of two primes are even, and there are infinite primes, how is Goldbach's Conjecture a conjecture? This is very strange for me

Comment: ah I think I see now what is missing is the proof of the infinitude of *twin* primes